# Gap between Status bar and modal view

Tags: iphone

Why there is gap between the status bar and the modalview? Can someone please help me with this to remove the gap between the status bar and modal view.

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(displayModalViewaction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];


  - (void)displayModalViewaction: (id) sender 
    {

self.viewController = [[Infoviewcontroller alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];  

[navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

  }
```

Thanks a lot in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the view frame size

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

fixed the gap between status bar and modal view.

Comment: Thanks, this brought me on the right way. In my case I had a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIScrollView` and the navigation controller overlapped the status bar after a view controller was presented modal. I hade to move down the `UINavigationBar` within the `UIViewController` down by 20px in `viewWillAppear`.